# Compute the Centroid of a Semicircle without Calculus

Tags: geometry

Can the centroid of a semicircle be computed without deferring to calculus or a limiting procedure?

Comment: Maybe that depends on what you consider "calculus".  Archimedes found that the center of gravity of a solid hemisphere is $5/8$ of the way from the "north pole" to the center of the sphere by using methods similar to Cavalieri's principle, but a bit more elaborate.

Comment: Yes, I suspect some variation of Cavalieri's principle would work. Just seems like there should be a nice geometric or trigonometric argument.

Answer (score 2):

The following may be acceptable to you as an answer. You can use the [**centroid theorem of Pappus**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem)

I do not know whether you really mean half-circle (a semi-circular piece of wire), or a half-disk. Either problem can be solved using the theorem of Pappus.

When a region is rotated about an axis that does not go through the region, the volume of the solid generated is the area of the region times the **distance** travelled by the centroid.

A similar result holds when a piece of wire is rotated. The surface area of the solid is the length of the wire times the distance travelled by the centroid.

In the case of rotating a semi-circular disk, or a semi-circular piece of wire, the volume (area) are known.

**Remark:** The result was known some $1500$ years before Newton was born. And the volume of a sphere, also the surface area, were known even before that. The ideas used to calculate volume, area have, in hindsignt, limiting processes at their heart. So if one takes a broad view of the meaning of "calculus," we have not avoided it.

Comment: I am looking for the centroid of the semicircular disk (half-disk). I would like to be able to prove the formula for the volume of a sphere using Pappus' theorem.

Comment: The long lost but now found *Method* of Archimedes gives a procedure, but it too is based fundamentally on limiting processes.